# I am getting a double login form with 2 usernames and passwords

Tags: django

I am getting 2 username and password fields on my login page. I tried to make a custom django authentication login page. The first username and password field that appeared on my page is the default login page given by django whereas the second pair is the formatted one which I tried to create using bootstrap. Here are my files:

Here is my login.html

```
    div class="container">
    <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
    {{form.as_p}}
    </div>
    <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Log In </button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

loginform.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    Username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    Password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import login,logout
from .loginform import LoginForm


urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.HomePageView, name='home'),
    path('accounts/login', login, {'authentication_form' : LoginForm},name='login'),
    path('accounts/logout',logout,name='logout')

]
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably because you defined `Username` and `Password` with uppercase first letter while the fields in `AuthenticationForm` are `username` and `password` with lower case first letters